# CSS not working Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css

My new site is not been displayed how it should be in internet explorer, in some parts of the site internet explorer dose not seem to be reading the css at all!

here is the css that ie is not reading can someone tell me what is wrong with it? or what i need to change to make it work in ie.

```
#reg_area {
border: 2px solid #ffffff;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px #cccccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px #cccccc;
background-color:#79af11;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#b2d545,#79af11);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%,color-stop(0, #b2d545),color-stop(1, #79af11));
text-align:center;
height:35px;
padding:10px;
font-family: Tw_Cen_MT_Condensed;
color: #DAF7A4;
font-size: 25px;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #2c4006;
}

#reg_area a:link {
font-family: Tw_Cen_MT_Condensed;
font-size: 45px;
color:#ffffff;
text-decoration:none;
}

#reg_area a:visited {
color:#ffffff;
}

#reg_area a:hover {
color:#D8F170;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Tw_Cen_MT_Condensed is not a web-safe font, hence won't be read.
- You have your gradient set up as background-image, not background
- Shadows don't work in IE
- Your Box Radius and Gradients point to Webkit browsers and Firefox, not IE.

Have you even looked into how to make stuff work in IE? Hint: Try to search for workarounds and what is missing for each issue you have on IE.

Answer (score 0):

Every line with -moz-

like -moz-border-radius: 15px;

will work only for mozilla (firefox)

It's probably the same with webkit.